# CSS transition-duration not working on form submit button

Tags: html, css

I've a problem with the transition-duration property.

It seems that doesn't work on the submit button of my form, but perfectly work on my main menu list item.

here's my HTML

```
     <form action="check_registration.php" autocomplete="on">
                <label for="nick">Identifiant : </label><input name="nick" type="text" required placeholder="Obligatoire"><br>
                <label for="password">Mot de Passe : </label><input name="password"type="password" required placeholder="Obligatoire"><br>
                <label for="email">Adresse mail : </label><input name="mail"type="email" required placeholder="Obligatoire"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Inscription" class="button col-center" ><br>
            </form>
```

Then my CSS

```
    #wrap form {

label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input{
    float: right;
}
.button{
    float: none;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(../../media/header.png);
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
}
.button:hover{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,150,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,195,110,1) 80%);
    transition-duration: 1.5s;
}}
```

I use SASS it's why the CSS is idented like this, I've already read the post called "Transition CSS duration not working" but the answer don't helped me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitions don't yet work with background gradients, even so switching from an image would not apply.

This effect can be done with a background element and transitioning the button transparency though.

http://codepen.io/justindunham/pen/rylLc

```
<div class="btn-wrap">
   <input type="submit" value="Inscription" class="button col-center" >
   <span class="button-bg"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

html

```
<form action="check_registration.php" autocomplete="on">
                <label for="nick">Identifiant : </label><input name="nick" type="text" required placeholder="Obligatoire"><br>
                <label for="password">Mot de Passe : </label><input name="password"type="password" required placeholder="Obligatoire"><br>
                <label for="email">Adresse mail : </label><input name="mail"type="email" required placeholder="Obligatoire"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Inscription" class="box" ><br>
            </form>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  background: #2db34a;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  transition-property: background;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  width: 95px;
    border:none;
}
.box:hover {
  background: #ff7b29;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nbt4Le0n/4/)